# Broadcasting an intent from a fragment to a service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

In an activity, when I send an intent to a service I just use `sendBroadcast`, but I cannot do the same from a fragment because a fragment has to be a static class. What is the best way of dealing with this?

I have considered having a method that receives a context, but this wouldn't work in the case of a fragment.

Currently my code is

```
public static class ExampleSectionFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_section_example, container, false);
        Bundle args = getArguments();

        //Example intent to broadcast to service on button press
        rootView.findViewById(R.id.action_start)
                .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(RECORDING_INTENT);
                         sendBroadcast(intent);
                    }
                });
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

sendBroadcast returns the error in eclipse:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method sendBroadcast(Intent) from the type ContextWrapper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Fragment`s are attached to an `Activity`, which is a subclass of `Context` - replace your `sendBroadcast` call (which is attempting to use the outer class' `sendBroadcast`) with `getActivity().sendBroadcast` - this will use the `Context` associated with `Activity` the `Fragment` is currently attached to.