# how to use send broadcast method in fragment class

Tags: android

I need a little bit of help.  I'm trying on the gps on a mobile.  No idea whether that works or not but before that I have set onclicklistener for the button but it does not allow to have sendbroadcast.  Anyone have solution for this?

```
public class locate extends Fragment {
    Button b1;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.locate, container, false);
    onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    b1=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.widget33);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(Gloabal.getcontext(), "text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent=new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
            intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
            sendBroadcast(intent);
            //startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return rootView;

}

}
```

any other alternative to use the intent ...m stuck a bit as m using swipeable tabs so dono much around that,any help is much appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [Broadcasting an intent from a fragment to a service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18687444/broadcasting-an-intent-from-a-fragment-to-a-service)

Answer (score 23):

**What you need is this code:**

```
   getActivity().sendBroadcast(intent);
```

**Edit 1:** *Some explanation -> Fragments are attached to an Activity, which is a subclass of Context which is required for sendBroadcast. So with getActivity().sendBroadcast() you will use the Context associated with Activity the Fragment is attached to at the moment.*

**Edit 2:** *I see in your Toast you are using Gloabal.getcontext(), replace that with getActivity()!!!*

Comment: that just did it mate,thanx

Comment: ya perfect,understood:)

Comment: Feel free to upvote and accept answer if it helped ;) its what keeps people helping and answering.

Comment: @user3203211: if you're still here, we would be grateful if you could *accept* this answer if it helped you (by ticking it). And if it was useful to you (this is the case here), you should *upvote* it too.

Comment: this is dangerous if the activity isn't attached yet