# Android : Using Broadcasting Receiver

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I want to read the SMS when it newly comes to my cellphone, I have implemented IncomingSms.java based on [this article](https://androidexample.com/incomming-sms-broadcast-receiver) to check for new SMS as

IncomingSms.java

```
public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

// Get the object of SmsManager
final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    try {

        if (bundle != null) {

            final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

            for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: " + senderNum + "; message: " + message);


                // Show Alert
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,
                        "senderNum: "+ senderNum + ", message: " + message, duration);
                toast.show();

            } // end for loop
        } // bundle is null

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

    }
}
```

}

but now the problem is I want to call `onReceive` in my other fragment to but I don't know what to pass as second argument in `onReceive` method which is demanding Intent ...

Comment: As per demanding Intent, you can pass the action and also pass the bundle value in Intent, which you can use in onReceive

Comment: You should never call `onReceive` directly, but [send a broadcast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237197/how-to-use-send-broadcast-method-in-fragment-class) from your context (in this case, the Fragment's Activity) instead. However, I fail to see what you want to achieve with this - can you tell us a bit more?

Comment: I want to detect sms as soon as it comes, but I am unable to find what to pass as second argument in OnReceive method. can you help with an example

Answer (score 1):

if you want call OnReceive ...

```
private void sendBroadcastToAPI() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    String action = "your reciver action";
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();//save data into bundle
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    intent.setAction(action);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you must add a public interface in your class and create a static instance from it.
2. in your fragment set interface
3. like this..!

   ```
   public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

   public interface IReceiveSMS{
     public void onReceiveData(/*inser your params here*/);
   }
   public static IReceiveSMS receiverSMS;
   // Get the object of SmsManager
   final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

   // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
   final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

   try {

       if (bundle != null) {

       final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

       for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

           SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
           String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

           String senderNum = phoneNumber;
           String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

           Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: " + senderNum + "; message: " + message);


           // Show Alert
           int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
           Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,
                   "senderNum: "+ senderNum + ", message: " + message, duration);
           toast.show();

       } // end for loop
     if(receiverSMS != null)
         receiverSMS.onReceiveData(/*inser your params here*/);
   } // bundle is null

      } catch (Exception e) {
     Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

       }
     }
   ```
4. in your fragment

   ```
     IncomingSms.receiverSMS = new IReceiveSMS{
       @Override
       public void onReceiveData(/*inser your params here*/)
       {
        //use params
       }
    }
   ```
5. enjoy

Comment: Please help me by telling  that how should I call onReceive() in my fragment

Comment: you cant call onReceive() in your fragment .android call automatically onReceive() .you just can use it